# If in the join t-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have a big t-sql stored procedure with this part that i am concerned about:

```
insert into @list
(
params
...
) 
select params
,..
,oip.someAttr
from @list2 as O
join dbo.abc oip
on oip.id = O.id
AND oip.prgId <> 4
join .. someother tables
...
where oipr.attrA = 1232
```

Now i want to write a logic that want for an additional parameter in the stored procedure 
"@value bit" if it is set then only the "AND condition above" should be checked otherwise not.

so if i do like

```
join dbo.abc oip
on oip.id = O.id
[AND]??? (i donot know).
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:
`AND (oip.prgId <> 4 OR @value = 0)`

Comment: i think i am silly :) have i stopped using my brain. Can you post any link where i can learn and practice this logical part of db-prog.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `oip.prgId` cannot possibly hold `0`s, here's another option to consider/try:

```
AND oip.prgId <> 4 * @value
```

If `@value` is 1, the right part of the inequality evaluates to `4`, and so the corresponding rows will be filtered out. If `@value` is `0`, however, then the expression becomes equivalent to `oip.prgId <> 0`, which would essentially mean *any value of `oip.prgId`* (since we've assumed that there can't be `0` values in the column).